# Is $T_1$ is biinterpretable with $T_2$ iff $T_1^{eq}$ is biinterpretable with $T_2^{eq}$?

Tags: model-theory

Is $T_1$ bi-interpretable with $T_2$ iff $T_1^{eq}$ is bi-interpretable with $T_2^{eq}$ ?

The forward direction seems clear to me, and given that bi-interpretability is an equivalence relation, then the converse should hold as well since if $T_1^{eq}\simeq T_2^{eq}$, $T_1\simeq T_1^{eq}$, and $T_2\simeq T_2^{eq}$, then $T_1\simeq T_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is immediate from the facts that (1) $T$ is bi-interpretable with $T^{\mathrm{eq}}$ and (2) bi-interpretability is an equivalence relation.